# Gradle does not import PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am trying to use PagerSlidingTabStrip (https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) in my Android project. I have added to my build.gradle the dependency, like the others libraries I use in the project (Gson, Volley...). All of these libraries works without problems, but PagerSlidingTabStrip doesn't work. I try to import it and use in my Activities and Fragments but I can't. 
I don't know what is the problem, and Android Studio don't show any error.

Comment: try to sync your project with gradle and check in Gradle COnsole if you are getting any error there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Delete or rename all of the `*.iml` files associated with this project and its modules. AFAICT, there is one at the project root and one in each module.
3. Restart Android Studio, allowing it to rebuild the `*.iml` files.

I ran into a similar situation yesterday, and this resolved it.